# Generate 4 digit sequential numbers keeping leading 0's starting form a given number

Tags: php, for-loop, printf

I am trying to generate 4 digit sequential numbers starting from any given number. Where I am stuck is keeping the leading 0's as I'll need 4 digits all the time. Here is my code.

```
$start = '0520';
for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    echo ($start + $i) . ',';
}
```

It gives me output like this..

`520,521,522,523,524,525,526,527,528,529,530,531,532,` and so on..

Therefor I tried several answers here in SO, but the nearest I reached is having 5 digits number with this

```
$start = '0520';
for($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
   echo sprintf('%05d', ($start + $i)) . ',';
}
```

It outputs 5 digit sequential numbers starting with `00520`.

What would be the best way to generate 4 digit sequential numbers keeping the leading 0's?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `echo sprintf('%04d', ($start + $i)) . ',';`?

Comment: @Marco Oops.. I guess I need to take a break!! That worked.

Comment: Well, no need of complicated functions if all you need is just a leading 0, just echo it before the number. `echo '0',($start + $i) . ',';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution, very easy, is to use

```
echo sprintf('%04d', ($start + $i)) . ',';
```

I think you missed **04** :D

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$start = 520;
$generatedNumbers = [];
for ($i = 0; $i <= 100; $i++) {
    $generatedNumbers[] = '0' . $start+$i;
}

print_r($generatedNumbers);
```